# Access different site collection using client OM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have written a little app, which makes use of the ECMA client OM. I need to access from a site-collection "/sites/subsite" a list, which is located on the site-collection "/".

However, this shows a security-validation error.

Is there any way to work around this problem - without disabling security-validation for the web-application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to manually use the web services on the client side, perhaps using SPServices, to interact with the site collection, to get to the data you require.

Comment: That sucks. What's a client OM good for, if I have to do everything by hand :(

Comment: That is the default security behavior. You can't do anything about it.

Comment: Client OM's widest use is within the same site collection, as that is the context of most users.